# Wordpress count results for post_title not working with foreach

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I have this code:

```
$data = "test 1, test 2, test 3, test 4, test 5";
$verify = explode(',', $data);
 foreach($verify as $datatoverify){
   echo $wpdb->get_var("SELECT count(post_title) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title LIKE '$datatoverify'");
}
```

The "test 3" and "test 5" exists in database.
With the code above it shows `00000` as output.
If i make the echo with a value (test 3 or test 5) it echos `2` that exists.

```
echo $wpdb->get_var("SELECT count(post_title) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title LIKE 'test 3'");
```

Why isn't working with foreach? What i'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I found what the problem was, I had to add a `trim($datatoverify)` to strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = "test 1, test 2, test 3, test 4, test 5";
$verify = explode(', ', $data);
 foreach($verify as $datatoverify){
   echo $wpdb->get_var("SELECT count(post_title) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title LIKE '".$datatoverify."'");
}
```

TRY this I hope it works :D